# Why does this pattern with Plus not work for numbers?

Tags: evaluation

I have a very simple question about redefining basic built-in functions, such as `Plus`. I'm pretty sure someone must have asked a similar question around here, but I couldn't find one. Consider the following code:

```
Unprotect[Plus];
x_ + y_ := x y
Protect[Plus];
```

For symbols this works as expected:

```
x+y
(* ---> x y *)
```

For numbers, however, the new definition does not work:

```
1+2
(* ---> 3 *)
```

Of course I know that it is stupid to use something like this and that defining functions or using upvalues etc. is the way to go here, but I'm really interested in why this happens. Can the pattern for `Plus` be defined in such a way that it works for numbers as well? Is `Plus[1,2]` evaluated internally *before* the pattern can be matched?

Comment: And here is a very simple answer: don't do it.

Comment: Have you read the question? I'm not interested in workarounds or whether or not it's a good idea to do this (of course it isn't!). I thought mabye someone could explain to me what happens so I get a better understanding of what Mma does.

Comment: IMO, this internal mechanics of `Plus` should not be relevant to the user. To me, this seems one of those internal details which can not serve you well even if you know them. `Plus`, `Times` and perhaps a few more fundamental functions have deviations from the standard evaluation semantics, so that certain buit-in rules like the one you illustrated apply before the user-defined rules. The whole fact that this was done in this way shows that those rules were considered *very* fundamental by developers, which brings the question again: how would the knowledge of exact semantics here be helpful?

Comment: Operations like `Plus` and `Times` are deeply wired in the system and cannot be modified beyond a certain point, as they're essential to pretty much everything else. For example, try: `Unprotect@Plus;
Remove@Plus; 1+1` Look ma! No `Plus`! But you still get 2. However `Plus[1,1]` remains unevaluated.

Comment: I somehow thought it was interesting to find out where this point, to which they *can* be modified is, no matter if this is useful or not. But now I'm thinking of deleting the question. The fundamental difference between how `Plus` works for numbers and symbols was just something that seemed strange to me.

Comment: I think that this is a rather important detail, and perhaps having this question around would be nice, since people come back to this every now and then. Just a day ago there was a similar question on Mathgroup. It is just this kind of detail where pretty much all one can say is "you do want to know about the mere fact of it, but you don't want to know anything deeper than that".

Comment: No, I don't think you should delete this question. I personally think it would be good to have this answered, as I do not know the _actual_ answer either, beyond what I've written. I've just never had a need to alter something as fundamental as `Plus`, but a comprehensive answer that also touches upon what might break if hypothetically one were to do this would be really great to have.

Comment: Okay, maybe someone can give some real insight into this at some point. At the very least, this will serve as a future reference. Maybe a post with some experiments and comparison between different functions and patterns, including what you said about the nature of such fundamental functions, will be enough to have this answered.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See [Plus](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plus.html) in the reference manual:

> Unlike other functions, Plus applies built-in rules before
>   user-defined ones. As a result, it is not possible to make definitions
>   such as `2+2=5`.

The ability for user-defined rules to supersede built-in ones was lost in [Version 3](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#21514140)

Comment: Note the same restriction applies to [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html).