# Cannot Block Plus

Tags: evaluation, scoping, core-language, built-in-symbols

It is customary to use the following idiom to partially evaluate something inside a held expression:

```
f[x_] := 2 x
Block[{f}, Hold[f[1 + 1]] /. x_f :> With[{r = x}, r /; True]]

Out[]= Hold[f[2]]
```

This works also with built-in symbols, like

```
Block[{Abs}, Hold[Abs[1 + 1]] /. x_Abs :> With[{r = x}, r /; True]]

Out[]= Hold[Abs[2]]
```

However, I cannot understand the behaviour of the following

```
Block[{Plus}, Hold[1 + 2*2] /. x_Plus :> With[{r = x}, r /; True]]
```

which returns `Hold[5]` instead of `Hold[1+4]`. Can someone explain why?

Comment: `Times` has the same issue, so I suspect they're wired into the parser at a deep lvl in the name of efficiency.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3261/block-attributes-of-equal

Comment: I believe this is the reason: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/why-does-this-pattern-with-plus-not-work-for-numbers/19129#19129

Answer (score 7):

I think my answer to [Why does this pattern with Plus not work for numbers?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/why-does-this-pattern-with-plus-not-work-for-numbers/19129#19129) is also the answer here.

---

See [Plus](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Plus.html) in the reference manual:

> Unlike other functions, Plus applies built-in rules before
>   user-defined ones. As a result, it is not possible to make definitions
>   such as `2+2=5`.

The ability for user-defined rules to supersede built-in ones was lost in [Version 3](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/IncompatibleChanges.html#21514140).

---

There is a similar property for [`Times`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Times.html).

Here is some evidence that rules for `Plus` are applied internally even when `Plus` is blocked:

```
Block[{Plus}, 1 + 2*2 /. Plus -> List]
(*  5  *)

p[x__] := Plus[x];
Block[{p}, p[1, 2*2] /. p -> List]
(*  {1, 4}  *)
```

*Update -- some more evidence:*

```
Block[{Plus}, 
  Hold[1 + 2*2] /. x_Plus :> With[{r = x}, r /; True]] // Trace
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Block[{p}, 
  Hold[p[1, 2*2]] /. x_p :> With[{r = x}, r /; True]] // Trace
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Michael, I marked this question as a duplicate.  Please let me know if you disagree.  Also I suspect you meant to link to 19126 rather than 3261 when you wrote "my answer to ..."

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't disagree.  I considered proposing it, but I wasn't sure I had nailed the reason.  -- And thanks, for pointing out I had copied the wrong link!

Comment: It occurs to me that I have a work-around that is applicable here but not in the original as marked.  Do you think I should reopen for that or just append it here in passing?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If it were me with such a work-around, I would probably nominate for re-opening.  (I have done so in the past.)  But it's up to you.

Comment: I posted.  Let me know what you think or if you find problems with it, please.

Answer (score 3):

I closed this as a duplicate of [Why does this pattern with Plus not work for numbers?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/why-does-this-pattern-with-plus-not-work-for-numbers) but I *think* I have something that is general enough to be useful, and it's not applicable to that question.

We may observe that although a plain use of `Block[{Plus}, . . .]` does not prevent numeric evaluation of `Plus` we can still make a substitution that does:

```
Block[{Plus = plus}, Hold @@ {2 + 2}]
```

> ```
> Hold[plus[2, 2]]
> ```

From there we could replace `plus` with `Plus` again.  Automating this process:

```
Attributes[hardBlock] = {HoldAll};

hardBlock[sym : {___Symbol}, body_] :=
  Block[sym, sym = #; body] /. Thread[# :> sym] & @ Module[sym, sym]
```

Now:

```
expr := Hold @@ {1 + 2 + 3*4}

Block[{Plus, Times}, expr]   (* original Block behavior for reference *)

hardBlock[{Plus},        expr]
hardBlock[{Times},       expr]
hardBlock[{Plus, Times}, expr]
```

> ```
> Hold[15]
>
> Hold[1 + 2 + 12]
> Hold[3 + 3 4]
> Hold[1 + 2 + 3 4]
> ```

And for completeness:

```
hardBlock[{Plus}, Hold[1 + 2*2] /. x_Plus :> With[{r = x}, r /; True]]
```

> ```
> Hold[1 + 2 2]
> ```

Comment: Have you looked at `hardBlock[{Plus}, Hold[1 + 2*2] /. x_Plus :> With[{r = x}, r /; True]] // Trace`? I think the `Plus` inside `Hold` is neither changed nor replaced. Consider `hardBlock[{Plus}, Hold[1 + 2*2] /. HoldPattern[x_Plus] :> With[{r = x}, r /; True]]` instead. (The thing that made me wonder was that `2*2` did not become `4`.)

Comment: @Michael Thank you!  I worried there would be problems like that I had failed to think through.  I'll have to consider how this case might be improved, or if this construct still has a purpose. :-/