# Evaluation inside Inactivate

Tags: evaluation, hold

The [documentation for `Inactivate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inactivate.html) makes the function sound really powerful because it gives granular control over which kind of expressions specifically **not** to evaluate.

> `Inactivate[expr,patt]`
>
> inactivates all symbols in *expr* that match the pattern *patt*.

Can then anyone explain to me this behavior of `Inactivate`?

```
Inactivate[{Print@1,Print@2}, Print] /. Inactivate@Print[a_]:> a //Activate
```

> {1,2}

```
Inactivate[Print/@{1,2}, Print] /. Inactivate@Print[a_]:> a //Activate
1
2
```

> {Null, Null}

A more useful application for this kind of scenario would be a workaround to make `Flatten` handle lists containing atoms. (Which does not work)

```
Inactivate[Flatten/@{1, {2, {3}}}, Flatten] 
/. Inactivate@Flatten[a_?AtomQ]:> a //Activate
```

while this works again:

```
Inactivate[{Flatten@1,Flatten@{2, {3}}}, Flatten] 
/. Inactivate@Flatten[a_?AtomQ]:> a //Activate
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This statement from documentation might be misleading. It should be read in conjunction with first statement:

> `Inactivate[expr]`
>
> replaces all instances of `f` with `Inactive[f]` for symbols `f` used as heads in `expr`.

So `Inactivate[expr, patt]` really inactivates all symbols **used as heads** in `expr`, that match the pattern `patt`.

That's why in e.g. `f[]` expression `f` is inactivated:

```
ClearAll[f]
Inactivate[f[], f] // FullForm
(* Inactive[f][] *)
```

and in `f` expression - it's not:

```
Inactivate[f, f] // FullForm
(* f *)
```

In expression you passed to `Inactivate`:

```
Print /@ {1, 2} // Hold // FullForm
(* Hold[Map[Print, List[1, 2]]] *)
```

`Print` is not used as head of expression, so it's not inactivated.

Instead of `Inactivate[Print/@{1,2}, Print]` you could manually wrap `Print` with `Inactive` head:

```
Inactive[Print] /@ {1, 2} /. Inactivate@Print[a_] :> a // Activate
(* {1, 2} *)
```

Answer (score 5):

[jkuczm](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/14303/jkuczm) already explained your example, but pragmatically I think you may be looking for [`Block`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Block.html) instead:

```
Block[{Flatten},
 Flatten /@ {1, {2, {3}}} /. Flatten[a_?AtomQ] :> a
]
```

> ```
> {1, {2, 3}}
> ```

Of course there are other ways to perform this specific operation, e.g.

```
Flatten@*List @@@ {1, {2, {3}}}
```

> ```
> {1, {2, 3}}
> ```

This one works because [`Apply`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html) does not modify atoms<sup>[(1)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46248/121)</sup>.

---

Note: `Block` may fail when using Packed Arrays, as some functions trigger low-level optimized code that `Block` does not affect.  See:

- [Block attributes of Equal](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3261/121)
- [Cannot Block Plus](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/89832/121)