# How to change the built-in function?

Tags: functions, function-construction

As you can see,the original `Differences` will get `{}` when your parameter is a list with one element just.

Differences /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}}

> {{1, 1}, {1}, {}}

Then we can change it like this

```
Unprotect[Differences];
Differences[{a_}] := {a};
Differences /@ {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6}}
```

> {{1, 1}, {1}, {6}}

But the same method don't fit the `Times` and `Divide`

```
Unprotect[Times];
Times[0, 0] := "NAN"
Times[0, 0]
0*0
Times[2, 3]
```

[image]

Or like the `Divide`

```
Unprotect[Divide];
Divide[0, 0] := "NAN"
Divide[0, 0]
0/0
Divide[2, 3]
```

[image]

Comment: Still a bit unclear - do you want to change `Times` etc? This is a really bad idea for such elementary functions, as it will mess up your system in unpredictable ways and bite you in the end. Is there a deeper reason not to use a custom function?

Comment: Thanks for your advice very much,but I wanna change it still in my situation.

Comment: There is a lot of indication that the built-in mathematical operations are deeply wired into the parser to speed up their operations, unlike `Differences`. So, adding `DownValues` for them is not very effective.

Comment: I am curious to see if/what @DanielLichtblau might report on messing with `Times` and friends.

Comment: You should define new functions that deal with the special cases and *then* defer to `Times`, `Divide`, `Differences` etc. to process the non-special cases afterwards. There is simply no way to reliably change `Times`, for example. Its definition is hard-coded into the system. Even if you could, you shouldn't: do you really think *Mathematica*'s own functions don't rely on a consistent concept of multiplication?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19126/why-does-this-pattern-with-plus-not-work-for-numbers

Comment: It seems to work with `Divide`.  If I read your output correctly, `Divide[0, 0]` yields `"NAN"`.  Note that `0/0` is translated to `Times[0, Power[0, -1]]` before being fed to the kernel for evaluation [[(39200)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39200)].